# DurandalJS - shell not loaded in #applicationHost

Tags: jquery, shell, knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

After I set every thing up and run my application, On the network I can see that shell.html is fetched but is not loaded in the div tag with id of applicationHost as it supposed to. Also, no errors occur so I figure out what is wrong. Could someone please help?

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "text": "text",
        "durandal": "durandal",
        "plugins": "durandal/plugins",
        "transitionions": "durandal/transitions",
        "viewmodels": "viewmodels",
        "views": "views",
        "logger": "services/logger",
        "system": "durandal/system",
        "app": "durandal/app",
        "viewLocator": "durandal/viewLocator"
    }
});


define(['system', 'app', 'viewLocator', 'logger'], function (system, app, viewLocator, logger) {

    system.debug();

    viewLocator.useConvention();

    app.start().then(function () {
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
    });

});
```

**shell.js**

```
define(['system', 'logger'],
    function (system, logger) {

        var shell = {
            activate: activate
        };

        return shell;

        function activate() {
            logger.log('Application is Loaded!', null, system.getModuleId(shell), true);
        }
});
```

**index.cshtml - body**

```
<body>
    <div id="applicationHost">
        @RenderPage("_splash.cshtml")
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/vendor")
    <script src="~/Scripts/require.js" data-main="App/main"></script>
</body>
```

**shell.html**

```
<div>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="brand" href="/">
                    <span class="title">Code Camper</span>
                    <span class="jump-start-title">[Jumpstart] 00-Durandal - 1 Page</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-inner navbar-secondary"></div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="content" class="main container-fluid">
        <!-- ko compose: {model: 'speakers', activate: true} -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </section>
</div>
```

[This is what i mean by Fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFHc3.png)

What i mean by not loaded is that it's not displayed where it should be in the #applicationHost replacing the splash screen.

[This is how my folders and files are set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoxV2.png)

Comment: How do you know it's not loaded?

Comment: It's Fetched but not viewed on the screen where it should be so it's not loaded :)

Comment: As i stated when i watch the network i can see that shell.html is fetched by text.js as the initiator however for some reason it's not loaded in the div tag.

Comment: You haven't included your shell.html or anything.  If your logger is showing that it is loaded than it is loaded, right?

Comment: I updated my question hope this help you get a clear view

Comment: Not sure how to help you - you aren't including your shell.html

Comment: I just did hope that helps.

Comment: Where is your router config for the valid paths?

Comment: The paths are not the problem at all am following the convention and am also getting the resources the shell.html is sent from the server again my problem is that it's not being displayed.

Comment: From reading your `require.config({...})`, your `main.js` file and your `views` and `viewmodels` directories are in the same directory as Durandal? If they're not, then your paths are all wrong.

Comment: Yes they are, all of them are under a folder called App, again am not inventing the wheel am just following the naming conventions, I am still learning durandal so am not tryin to be fancy at all.

Comment: Since you are on .net try using the .net starterkit where you get the proper structure.

Comment: On `data-main`, try changing to `/App/main` (forward-slash at the start).  Also, try changing your `activate` method in **shell.js** to the following: `var activate = function () {...}` and move it to above `var shell`.  Take each change one by one.  Also, FWIW, I render my splash with `@Html.Partial`, but I don't know if that matters in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your time @EricTaylor I'll try and see if that is gonna fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong eventually it came down to where i place the durandal folder so i tried moving it to the Scripts folder and it worked don't know why but apparently durandal is set to work there if some one can explain that behavior and how to change it please share your knowledge with me, and thanks to every one who contributed to this question and tried to help :).

Comment: Your main.js is where you set the location of the folders.

Comment: Then it remains a mystery why it did not work because i set the routes in main.js still that didn't help or maybe am just unlucky, any way thanks again @PW Kad i see that i still need to get a good grasp on how this library and it's dependencies work.

Comment: I know it's the requirejs dependency i read the documentation but yet it's not a very good one hope they improve it a little bit, and thanks again @PW Kad am really grateful for you taking from your time to help me.